# pushing symfony 2 app to heroku, closed by remote host

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

I want push my app writen in Symfony 2 PHP to heroku server. I use Ubuntu 14.04. When i pushed my app i see:

```
-----> PHP app detected

 !     WARNING: Your composer.json requires an unknown PHP version.
       Defaulting to PHP 5.5.14; install may fail!
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/php

-----> Setting up runtime environment...
       - PHP 5.5.14
       - Apache 2.4.9
       - Nginx 1.4.6
-----> Installing PHP extensions:
       - opcache (automatic; bundled, using 'ext-opcache.ini')
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 745dcbce3317f7119575c39cef2cb601f9c5ffcf 2014-06-29 16:49:45
Connection to 10.179.144.249 closed by remote host.
, done.
error: did not receive remote status
```

Maybe it's my internet provider fault?

**UPDATE**
I have omposer.lock in my project directory, my composer.json is:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "dvelopment/firephp-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/serializer": "2.5.*@dev",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "dev-master",
        "luxifer/doctrine-functions": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well what version of PHP are you requiring in your composer.json file ?

Comment: Post your composer.json, did you have composer.lock file?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a php version that they do not support

Supported versions
PHP
5.5.11
5.5.12
5.5.13
5.5.14 (default)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support

Modify your composer.json and change it to ~5.5.11

This also might be helpful to you in the future:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony2

Comment: That's not the issue, the warning is bogus. 5.5.11 is in the range of the `>=5.3.3` selector. There are notes in Dev Center saying that these warnings can currently be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ISP is closing the connection after a couple of seconds. Have you tried running `time git push heroku master` a few times to see if it always stops after more or less the same amount of time ("real" is the value you should look at)?